# Performance testing in Dynamics 365 for Operations - no endpoint listening

Tags: performance-testing, load-testing, dynamics-365-operations

**Short error description:**

`Ms.Dynamics.Performance.CreateUsers.exe` from PerfSDK throws **error**

> There was no endpoint listening at https://mytest.sandbox.operations.dynamics.com/Services/AxUserManagement/Service.svc/ws2007FedHttp that could accept the message.

**Long error description:**

I have created a single user C# test from an XML recording and run it with PerfSDK successfully as described in the first part of the **[PerfSDK and multiuser testing with Visual Studio Online](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/operations/dev-itpro/perf-test/perfsdk-tutorial)** guide.

I am having trouble running multiuser load tests as described in the second part of the lab. The link above seems to be the only resource online describing how a multiuser test can be created from a singleuser test and how Visual Studio Online can be used to run it in a sandbox environment. I've also watched a few videos such as [Tools to Measure and Improve Microsoft Dynamics AX Performance](https://mbspartner.microsoft.com/AX/Videos/967), [Performance Tools](https://mbspartner.microsoft.com/AX/Videos/845) and the like, but none of them explains all the steps that need to be taken in as much detail as the above article.

I've done the following:

1. Created a recording of a scenario with Task Recorder in **Dynamics 365
   for Operations**.
2. Created C# perf test from recording in Visual Studio using the
   `PerfSDKSample` project from the `PerfSDK` folder.
3. Followed all 'Steps to run single user performance test with Perf
   SDK' from the [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/operations/dev-itpro/perf-test/perfsdk-tutorial#steps-to-run-single-user-performance-test-with-perf-sdk);
4. Built the solution and successfully ran my test from Test Explorer:
   Internet Explorer opened starting and replaying the scenario that I
   had recorded.

Note: I used DEV environment [usnconeboxax1aos.cloud.onebox.dynamics.com](https://usnconeboxax1aos.cloud.onebox.dynamics.com) for testing. When I tried using another hostname in `CloudEnvironment.Config` (a sandbox, e.g. [mysandbox.sandbox.operations.dynamics.com](https://mysandbox.sandbox.operations.dynamics.com)), the singleuser test failed with the following **error message**:

> System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'MS.Dynamics.TestTools.CloudCommonTestUtilities.Authentication.UserManagement' threw an exception. ---> System.ServiceModel.EndpointNotFoundException: There was no endpoint listening at https://mysandbox.sandbox.operations.dynamics.com/Services/AxUserManagement/Service.svc/ws2007FedHttp that could accept the message. This is often caused by an incorrect address or SOAP action. See InnerException, if present, for more details. ---> System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found..

5. For multiuser testing, I launched Visual Studio from Visual Studio
   Online portal https://app.vssps.visualstudio.com/profile/view
6. I modified the TestSetup method as follows:

*Single-user TestSetup:*

```
public void TestSetup()
{
    SetupData();
    _userContext = new UserContext(UserManagement.AdminUser);
    Client = DispatchedClient.DefaultInstance;
    Client.ForceEditMode = false;
    Client.Company = "GB01";
    Client.Open();
}
```

*Multi-user TestSetup:*

```
public void TestSetup()
{
    var testroot = System.Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("DeploymentDir");
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(testroot))
    {
        testroot = System.IO.Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
    }
    Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("testroot", testroot);
    if (this.TestContext != null)
    {
        timerProvider = new TimerProvider(this.TestContext);
    }
    SetupData();
    _userContext = new UserContext(UserManagement.AdminUser);
    Client = new DispatchedClientHelper().GetClient();
    Client.ForceEditMode = false;
    Client.Company = "GB01";
    Client.Open();
}
```

7. I set the HostName in `CloudEnvironment.Config` to the sandbox URL e.g. [mysandbox.sandbox.operations.dynamics.com](https://mysandbox.sandbox.operations.dynamics.com).
8. Logged in to the sandbox machine and installed the certificate I had generated earlier for the single-user testing.
9. Updated wif.config on the sandbox machine in the same way it had been updated in DEV earlier, and restarted IIS.
10. Double-clicked `vsonline.testsettings` in Solution Explorer and used the settings recommended in the above [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/operations/dev-itpro/perf-test/perfsdk-tutorial#setup-visual-studio-online-for-multiuser-testing) (accordingly modified for my certificate and test scenario).
11. Opened `SampleLoadTest.loadtest` from Solution Explorer and tweaked it to use only my test in the Test Mix node, reduced test duration and user count.
12. Run the load test.

The load test ended with a few errors. The first **TestError** is the same as mentioned above:

> Initialization method MS.Dynamics.Performance.Application.TaskRecorder.GenJnlBase.TestSetup threw exception. System.TypeInitializationException: System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'MS.Dynamics.TestTools.CloudCommonTestUtilities.Authentication.UserManagement' threw an exception. ---> System.ServiceModel.EndpointNotFoundException: There was no endpoint listening at https://mysandbox.sandbox.operations.dynamics.com/Services/AxUserManagement/Service.svc/ws2007FedHttp that could accept the message. This is often caused by an incorrect address or SOAP action. See InnerException, if present, for more details. ---> System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found..

13. Finally, even though I was able to run `Ms.Dynamics.Performance.CreateUsers.exe` on my DEV machine successfully (a number of test AX users were created in [usnconeboxax1aos.cloud.onebox.dynamics.com](https://usnconeboxax1aos.cloud.onebox.dynamics.com)), when the sandbox environment URL was set in `CloudEnvironment.Config`, `Ms.Dynamics.Performance.CreateUsers.exe` failed with same **error**:

> C:\PerfSDK>Ms.Dynamics.Performance.CreateUsers.exe 3 GB01
>   Failed with the following error:
>   System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'MS.Dynamics.TestTools.CloudCommonTestUtilities.Authentication.UserManagement' threw an exception. ---> System.ServiceModel.EndpointNotFoundException: There was no endpoint listening at https://mytest.sandbox.operations.dynamics.com/Services/AxUserManagement/Service.svc/ws2007FedHttp that could accept the message. This is often caused by an incorrect address or SOAP action. See InnerException, if present, for more details.
>   ...
>   Exception rethrown at [0]:
>      at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)
>      at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type)
>      at MS.Dynamics.TestTools.CloudCommonTestUtilities.AxUserManagementServiceReference.IAxUserManagement.EnumUsers()
>      at MS.Dynamics.TestTools.CloudCommonTestUtilities.Authentication.UserManagement.PopulateAxUsers()
>      at MS.Dynamics.TestTools.CloudCommonTestUtilities.Authentication.UserManagement..cctor()
>      --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
>      at MS.Dynamics.TestTools.CloudCommonTestUtilities.Authentication.UserManagement.get_AdminUser()
>      at MS.Dynamics.Performance.CreateUsers.Program.Main(String[] args)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the [walkthrough](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/unified-operations/dev-itpro/perf-test/perfsdk-tutorial),

> If you have an ARR-enabled environment, i.e. you have 2 endpoints like
>   this:
>
> - apr-arr8aossoap.axcloud.test.dynamics.com
> - apr-arr8aos.axcloud.test.dynamics.com
>
> You would need to enter both endpoints in CloudEnvironment.Config
>
> [image: endpoints]

The `no endpoint listening` error can be resolved by specifying correct SOAP hostname, e.g.

```
<ExecutionConfigurations Key="HostName" Value="mysandbox.sandbox.operations.dynamics.com" />
<ExecutionConfigurations Key="SoapHostName" Value="mysandboxaossoap.sandbox.operations.dynamics.com" />
```